# How to get the distance of two point geometry in meters using NetTopologySuite?

Tags: c#, geometry, nettopologysuite

How to get the distance of two point geometry in meters using NetTopologySuite.

I have used the Distance() function, but I'm getting some values and I couldn't identify the unit of those values. Its for a c# application to neglect the tolerance value of 20 meters to be ignored.

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using GeoAPI.Geometries;

private static double findistance()
{
   var geomFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
   IGeometry geometry1 = geomFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(12.977299, 77.571075));
   IGeometry geometry2 = geomFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(12.977277, 77.571258));
   var distance = geometry1.Distance(geometry2);
   return distance;
}
```

I need to get the distance calculated in meters.

Answer (score 1):

Per [docs](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/html/), SRID 4326 stands for definition below

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
  UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

`UNIT["degree"...` tells us that the result you are getting has values in degrees. We can calculate distance in meters, if we transform these points into Projected Coordinated system. `ProjNET4GeoAPI` package could do that for us.

```
private static double findDistance()
{
    CoordinateTransformationFactory ctfac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

    var from = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
    var to = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;

    var trans = ctfac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(from, to);
    var mathTransform = trans.MathTransform;

    var p1Coordinate = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(12.977299, 77.571075);
    var p2Coordinate = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(12.977277, 77.571258);

    p1Coordinate = mathTransform.Transform(p1Coordinate);
    p2Coordinate = mathTransform.Transform(p2Coordinate);

    return p1Coordinate.Distance(p2Coordinate);
}
```

Comment: This will result in huge errors, especially if geometries are far away from each other.

Comment: @DmytroGokun thanks for the feedback. I am new to this topic myself, and when I had similar question, this is the best thing I have found. for my project I used `ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WGS84_UTM(30, true)` since it covered required country, but this will be inaccurate if point is outside the zone? I thought `WebMercator` is something like "average" on accuracy when we don't know exact zone?

Comment: @DmytroGokun will be glad if you post any suggestions to this answer

Comment: No, I do not know a solution. Previously, i used Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to calculate the distance properly, but it is not available for .NET Core, only for .NET Framework. If that is fine for you, it still works.

Comment: @DmytroGokun: _"I used Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to calculate the distance"_ Do you know of any sample code illustrating how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Pythagoras theorem to calculate the distance.

Here are the steps:

1. Get Deltas

   - double int deltaX = Math.Abs(point1.X - point2.X);
   - double int deltaY = Math.Abs(point1.Y - point2.Y);
2. Pythagoras formula

   - double distance = Math.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));

If you want to calculate a 3D point it is the same steps except calculate the DeltaZ and then the formula is distance = X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2